# How to get the complete output from expect when the internal buffer size of expect_out(buffer) size exceeds?

Tags: tcl, expect

I dont know whats happening but i am not getting the complete output from the remote command executed possibly because expects internal buffer is getting execceded.

```
    proc SendCommands { Commands } {
            global prompt log errlog
                    foreach element [split $Commands ";"] {
                                    expect {
                                           -re $prompt
                                            {send -- "$element\r"}
                                           }
                                    set outcome "$expect_out(buffer)"
                             foreach line [split $outcome \n] {
                                       foreach word [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line] {

                                            if {( [string index [string trimleft $line " "] 0 ] == "%")} {
                                              puts  "$outcome"
                                               exit 1
                                            }
                                      }
                            }
                    puts "$outcome"
                   }

    }

    set timeout 30

    foreach  host [ split $hosts "\;" ] {
            spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "$username@$host"
    match_max   10000000

    expect {
      timeout { send_user "\nFailed to get password prompt\n"; exit 1 }
      eof { send_user "\nSSH failure for $host\n"; exit 1 }
           "*?assword:*"
          {
           send -- "$password\r"
          }

    }


    expect {
              timeout { send_user "\nLogin incorrect\n"; exit 1 }
              eof { send_user "\nSSH failure for $host\n"; exit 1 }

         -re  "$prompt"
           { send -- "\r" }
           }
    set timeout 300
    SendCommands "$Commands"
    }
```

this is how i am executing it :

```
./sendcommand aehj SWEs-elmPCI-B-01.tellus comnet1 "terminal length 0;show int description" "(.*#)$"
```

i am getting the complete output only when i remove `log user 0` but when i use the puts command in the fucnction sendcommands above i get about 90 percent of it with 10 percent
of the trailing data at the end is not shown.

one way i am thinking is to use negation of regex in expect but it doesn't seem to work.

```
                                    expect {
                                           -re ! $prompt
                                            {puts $expect_outcome(buffer)}
                                           }
```

EDIT :I get all the output once when its executed about 5 or 7 times

Answer (score 2):

After a little search i came up with this and seems to work but let me know of any execptions or better answers :

I set match_max = 1000 then

```
    expect {
           -re $prompt
          {send -- "$element\r"}

    full_buffer {
        append outcome $expect_out(buffer)
        exp_continue
    }

                                    }
append outcome $expect_out(buffer)
puts $outcome
```

but still when i set match_max = 10000 or 100 it fails again